# what is the difference between accessing a pci device using procfs vs sysfs

Tags: io, device, pci

`procfs` file: `/proc/bus/pci/00/00.0`

vs.

`sysfs` file: `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/resource`

I have seen some drivers use the `procfs` file and some use `sysfs`. What is the difference? For what I need, I find that `mmap`-ing the `sysfs/resource<n>?` file and read/write works as I need it to, but similar operation on the `procfs` file does not work. But obviously the `procfs` file is used successfully elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `procfs` file you cite (`/proc/bus/pci/00/00.0`) provides access to the device's configuration header. It is also accessible in `sysfs` as `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/config`.

The `sysfs` file you're talking about (`/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/resource<N>`) provides access to the device's BAR regions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space for an explanation of the relationships. Also, you may want to read the linux kernel documentation at 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs-pci.txt